# Fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS but I have no sound, only output device is Dummy Output

Tags: sound

Title says it all. If you need any more info I'll be very happy to provide, but right now my computer is almost unusable in Ubuntu (dual boot with Windows) because I have no sound. Thank you to anyone who replies!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling pulseaudio and alsamixer? also if you post a screenshot of what alsamixer and hdajackretask someone with more expertise than me might be able to help.

Comment: Hey Josef, yes I've tried pretty much every solution on the first three pages of Google search results. Would you happen to have Ubuntu installed on a Huawei laptop by any chance? I found out Huawei uses sound cards that don't play well with Ubuntu (for some reason) so I've given up. Fortunately, connecting a Bluetooth headset works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**It's a HARDWARE issue.**

Apparently, my Huawei laptop comes with a sound card that doesn't work with Ubuntu, at least according to the kind folks over at The Odin Project.

For now, I'll make do with my Bluetooth headphones which, fortunately, work just fine after a fresh install (I may have broken a few things in my attempts to fix the audio).